# Why doesn't Ctrl+F4 work in Notepad++?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

Why does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> not close a document that has been opened in [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)? Is there a way to enable it?

I have started using Notepad++ today and I expected <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to close the current document as in most other applications
on the Microsoft Windows platform (both non-Microsoft and Microsoft applications) with MDI (multiple document interface) or TDI (Tabbed document interface) interfaces:
[UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit), [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_(web_browser)), [Eudora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudora_(e-mail_client)), Firefox, [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org), Visual
Studio, etc.

Is there a reason for this?

Platform: Notepad++ v5.4.5, Windows XP 64 bit SP2, 8 GB RAM.

<sub>(Note: it is not enabled by default, but actually it can be enabled by changing the keyboard shortcut from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>: menu *Settings* -> *Shortcut Mapper* -> line 8, *Close* -> <right click> on Ctrl+W -> *Modify* -> Ctrl, F4 -> *OK* -> *Close*.)</sub>

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I don't actually know why it is set to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> but to answer your other question: To change the default tab closing behaviour, go to Settings > Shortcut Mapper. Change the Close shortcut [8] to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: `Ctrl + W` is widely used within FLOSS applications. Gnome f.e. uses that shortcut to close windows, and I bet so does KDE...oh, and Firefox btw too.

Comment: @Bobby: It isn't just FLOSS apps.  `Ctrl+W` is a standard CUA shortcut for `Close`, introduced by MacOS and adopted by Windows in the 1980s.

Comment: Ctrl+W works with almost all tabbed or multi-document applications like Excel, Word, Eclipse...

Answer (score 10):

By default, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> will close the current window. Notepad++ is not a Microsoft product, so it shouldn't be too surprising that it doesn't follow Windows 'conventions". If you go to Settings -> Shortcut Mapper you can change the Close function to map to whatever key combination you would like.

Comment: I guess its just something we got used to and love - It just makes sense to me to have Ctrl + F4 be the command to close. Most mainstream non-microsoft apps do it. Take Chrome and Firefox for example.

There's nothing forcing the app to do this except common sense

Comment: @Ciaran: Actually I'm used to ctrl-w, I mean, seriously, what microsoft app has tabs?! IE only got them *after* firefox, and in firefox it was ctrl-w, so I got used to that.

Comment: @hasen j: Good point. I think the first time I came across tabs was in  Firefox. And it just made sense to me to try ctrl + f4 to close a tab. And it worked so I stuck with it. It might have been before my time (or perhaps still is the case) that ctrl+w still works.

F4 makes sense because alt+f4 closes the whole window. I'm used to using that to close a window, so I'm used to ctrl+f4 to close a tab. Same works either way but I suppose its a comfort thing

Comment: Ctrl+W still works in Firefox. In fact, it's the shortcut listed in the menu as well.

Comment: @hasen: It's not about tabs. Every windows *MDI* application should implement ctrl-f4 to close a document en alt-f4 to close the application.

Comment: Both Microsoft and Apple have had user interface guidelines for more than 20 years. For instance expressed in the books "The Windows Interface. An Application Design Guide" (1987, ISBN 1-55615-439-9) and "Human Interface Guidelines: The Apple Desktop Interface" (1987, ISBN 0-201-17753-6). From the former, page 16, table 2.6, "Recommended PC Function Key Assignments", Ctrl+F4: "Close document window".

Comment: @Peter, I know they both have UI guides, but I'm certain there are places where they conflict. And since there are many applications deployed for both, those software providers have to make a choice of which to follow. I don't know that this is one of those cases, but regardless, I think the important thing is the ability to customize; which thankfully, notepad++ has.

Comment: It's about time MS changed thier guidelines then. Ctrl+F4 is an easy way to get wrist-ache.

Comment: `Alt+F4` and `Ctrl+F4` is a legacy carried over from the `MS-DOS` days, when all the popular apps had different keyboard shortcuts, while `Ctrl+W` is a standard introduced in MacOS and copied by Microsoft, along with `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+X, V, O, N`, etc.;